# Unique item from array when seeding data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, seeding

I was wondering how I could select a random item from an array each time I create a record when seeding.

I know to select a random item, I can use

```
array_one = ["one", "two", "three"]
array_one.sample
one
```

Or if I want to select each value one time only (sample takes an argument)

```
array_one = ["one", "two", "three"]
array_one.sample(3)
["two", "one", "three"]
```

But how would I do it in the following circumstance

```
email_address_array = ['myaddress@email.com', 'myaddress1@email.com', 'myaddress2@email.com']

3.times {
  user = User.create({
    email: email_address_array.sample ## not sure how to set this up  
  })
}
```

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your array has no duplicate values, you can do:

```
User.create(email: email_address_array.delete(email_address_array.sample))
```

This will return a random entry from the array while also deleting it from that array. This also assumes you don't need the array again later in your seeds file.

Answer (score 3):

Pop elements from [shuffled array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shuffle):

```
email_address_array = ['myaddress@email.com', 'myaddress1@email.com', 'myaddress2@email.com']
shuffled_email_address_array = email_address_array.shuffle

3.times {
  user = User.create({
    email: shuffled_email_address_array.pop
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to do the shuffle inside of the loop...

```
%w(one@example.com two@example.com three@example.com).shuffle.each do |random_email|
  User.create(email: random_email)
end
```